# Mysql Handles Locking automaticaly

Tags: mysql, locking

i am writing a PHP program with Mysql. i am new to Mysql. Do we need to apply locking when writing query or mysql innodb handles automatically the locking.?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has internal locking mechanisms as stated in the docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-locking.html).

Unless you have specific needs, that will work for you 90% of the time. However you can specify your own locking.

[Here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking/) is another introductory link to mysql locking